# Square V1 api request not working as per API docs

Tags: square-connect

We are experiencing errors with few of Square APIs, it was working a week back, now which is not working as per the documentation, anything changed recently related to square, not able to find out in news : https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/?q=employee#navsection-roles & https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/?q=employee#navsection-employees.

Request/Response in question.

---

Ex 1: With Valid role_ids too it's failing, which used to work 3-4 days back.

```
POST https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/employees HTTP/1.1
Host: connect.squareup.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer *****************************
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 120
{
  "first_name": "FIRST_NAME_TEST_SP",
  "last_name": "LAST_NAME_TEST_SP",
  "role_ids": ["T6u3cmJnH7eZbAlvPfql"]
}
--
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Request-Id: V6fCtNEkQB2p9lSpswcS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Response-Time: 296ms
Date: Fri, 28 Jul 2017 07:51:07 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=631152000
content-length: 74
{"type":"bad_request","message":"role_ids [T6u3cmJnH7eZbAlvPfql] invalid"}
```

---

Ex 2: As per API docs, role_ids is optional, but without it its failing.

```
POST https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/employees HTTP/1.1
Host: connect.squareup.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer *****************************
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 87
{
  "first_name": "FIRST_NAME_TEST_MIN_SP",
  "last_name": "LAST_NAME_TEST_MIN_SP"
}
--
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Request-Id: fjrobTpoQ/SqjGLjYY+f
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Response-Time: 286ms
Date: Fri, 28 Jul 2017 07:51:08 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=631152000
content-length: 54
{"type":"bad_request","message":"role_ids [] invalid"}
```

---

Ex 3: Permission is mandatory for creating roles, but now it's passing.

```
POST https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/roles HTTP/1.1
Host: connect.squareup.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer *****************************
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 71
{
  "name": "TEST_NAME_EMPTYPERMISSIONMIN_SP",
  "permissions": []
}
--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Request-Id: zPvmsdjdQr+KolWM85K/
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Response-Time: 245ms
Date: Fri, 28 Jul 2017 07:51:09 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=631152000
content-length: 176
{"permissions":[],"id":"pNxPulcufnUpifjqnR0Y","name":"TEST_NAME_EMPTYPERMISSIONMIN_SP","is_owner":false,"updated_at":"2017-07-28T07:51:09Z","created_at":"2017-07-28T07:51:09Z"}
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting! We will take a look. We also have a slack team for developers that you might be [interested in as well](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfAZGIEZoNs-XryKqUoW3atFQHdQw5UqXLMOVPq3V4DEq-AJw/viewform#response=ACYDBNj5LFgPy8Tcac2gSgv_IjXvgWsPy2CO2xTXwnc0OSSxCvWFgc7SCDHvVQ)

Comment: @nitin-kumar can you try Ex. 1 and Ex. 2 again? These are working for me currently, and are consistent with the docs. Ex. 3 should pass. `permissions` can be an empty array (you may create a role with no permissions).

Comment: @gorbster, thanks for looking into it.

I am still getting the same error, tried out just Ex 1, Ex 2. both failing for me with same errors

Comment: For Ex1 and Ex2 - I got response from Support team, mentioning number of Employees created has reached 600 for my account, which is the limit. As it's not documented and also the error response doesn't mentions that limit has reached.

Comment: Hi @nitin-kumar - I just followed up with our engineering team and what you heard from our support team is true. This is a bug we're working on where there are limitations when the number of employees is more than 600. May I ask number of employees that your business is trying to manage?

Comment: Hi @gorbster, sorry I won't be able to comment regarding that.